# .net identity server4 external database

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Im reading the docs and i can't figure out if is possible to use an external database some SQL (not social providers) instead of ADFS in the token issuing flow.

We basically want the user  to authenticate some credentials  against the database.

this is the scenario

1. User will receive one-time password.
2. Aplication will save the OTP and other credentials in the database.
3. User will challenge against the database with the otp and other credentials.
4. If challenge ok user will receive TOKEN with claims.

thanks

Comment: I don't understant what you want to do. What do you mean with "an external database" ?

Comment: @KevinB i added the scenario i looking to achieve

Comment: Okay, so you want to implement your own long-in flow ?

Comment: @KevinB exectly